# How to remove a relationship field with php

Tags: relationships, ee3

I have a "Teams" channel that has a relationship field to a "tournaments" channel.  On the frontend when I display all the teams for that tournament, I need to allow a user to remove their team from that tournament.  How do I go about doing this?  I still want to keep the team entry, just clear that relationship field so they aren't attached to a tournament anymore.  Not sure if there are meta data and all that you have to set.

Comment: You need to use channel forms in the front-end where logged in user can
edit their entry data.

Comment: I've been playing around with the channel form and trying to spit out the relationship field.  It seems to spit out a select box with all the tournaments if I use {field:relationship_field}.

How would they "deselect" their tournament from dropdown?  Not sure why it doesn't spit out the relationship selector from the CMS with a little search box they can use.

Comment: I have the CSS linked in the <head> based off docs
<link href="{path='css/_ee_channel_form_css'}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

not sure if there's an actual css file that should be sitting in my /css called "_ee_channel_form_css" or if that's a path that gets generated automatically from the EE install

Answer (score 1):

You can use external entries plugin like as below:

```
{exp:external_entries:delete table="exp_relationships" 
search:parent_id="{segment_1}" AND search:child_id="{segment_2}"  debug="no"}
```

Plugin is not available for `EE3` but it will still work in `EE3` just need to add the `addon.setup.php` file.

Comment: what do you mean just have to add the addon.setup.php file?  what's that consist of and how do I do this?  why haven't they updated it to EE3 compatible if it's that easy?

Comment: addon.setup.php file is required for the EE3 addons.This file provides descriptive data about a specific add-on such as author, name, and version.